# Can't install ActiveSupport for Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to install ActiveSupport on my pc which runs Win 8, but it fails and it gives me a list of things that went wrong.

See screenshot: http://imgur.com/2EP46TT

I installed the DevKit beforehand, in case this matters.
I'm very new to Ruby so I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

This is what was in the mkmf.log

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -march=native conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:

/* begin */

1: #include "ruby.h"

2:

3: #include

4: #include

5: int main(int argc, char **argv)

6: {

7:   return 0;

8: }

/* end */

Comment: do you actually have have x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc installed?  Because rubygems looks like it's trying to compile native extensions but can't locate a C++ Compiler.

Comment: I don't think I have. Isn't that part of the DevKit? 
I installed the first devkit download from this site: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
should I be installing something else?

Comment: Instead of rubyinstaller use rails installer, it include active support by default http://railsinstaller.org/en